# Add all even numbers between 18 and 27 using function PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I got exercise to do. Need Create a function called `printRange()` that should take 2 numbers as arguments, start and stop. The function should add all even numbers between start and stop (not including) to an array and return it.
Answer with a call to the function using the arguments: 18 and 27. Write your code below and put the answer into the variable ANSWER.

Need to use function coz exercise is about "learn function in PHP".

Check code below I came so long.

I was thinking if i use `$x .= $number;` so PHP put even $number to `$x=[];`but this doesn't work for me. The answer should be **[20,22,24,26] (array)**

```
$x = [];
function printRange($a, $b) {
    foreach (range($a, $b) as $number) {
        if (0 === $number % 2) {
            $x .= $number;
        }
    }

}


$ANSWER = printRange(18, 27);
```

I was trying to remove `$x .= $number;` and write echo $number: to check what i get. This is what i get **1820222426**

```
$x = [];
function printRange($a, $b) {
    foreach (range($a, $b) as $number) {
        if (0 === $number % 2) {
            echo $number;
        }
    }

}




$ANSWER = printRange(18, 27);
```

Comment: `$x []= $number;` is for array pushing.  You're doing string concatenation

Comment: Spidy senses thinks your @MatiUrbaniak, please dont multi account.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use the step in `range()`?

```
print_r(range(18, 27, 2));
//Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 20 [2] => 22 [3] => 24 [4] => 26 )
```

Comment: Very nice remark. If your answer wouldn't be a partly answer to the exercise as described by TS, I would upvote also.

Comment: And `array_sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$x .= $number;
```

You should probably do:

```
array_push($x, $number);
```

Comment: Or $x[] = $number; with a short syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
In $x .= $number;  .= is used to concatenate string. if you want to store this in array then modify your code like 
$x = [];
function printRange($a, $b) {
foreach (range($a, $b) as $number) {
    if (0 === $number % 2) {
        $x[] = $number; // $x[] will store your value in array
    }
}
echo implode(', ',$x); // if you want to store your result comma separated then use implode otherwise just print $x array.
}
$ANSWER = printRange(18, 27);
```